# Find number of messages in a Kafka topic using Java

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I am using [Kafka Utils](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html) to test a certain kafka based messaging system. I want to find out the number of messages in a particular topic without using **kafka-console-consumer.sh** script. I can't seem to find a KafkaTestUtils based way or any way in java to help me achieve this. None of the answers to other similar questions have helped me yet.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```java
Properties properties = ...
// omitted for the sake of brevity
KafkaConsumer<String,String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
consumer.subscribe(topic);
consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(10L)); // or some time

AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong();
consumer.endOffsets(consumer.assignment()).forEach( (topicPartition, endOffsetOfPartition) -> {
    count.addAndGet(endOffsetOfPartition);
});

// decrement in case of retention as pointed out by Mickael
consumer.beginningOffsets(consumer.assignment()).forEach( (topicPartition, startOffsetOfPartition) -> {
    count.set(count.get() - startOffsetOfPartition);
}));

System.out.println(count.get());
```

You get the *end* offsets for each partition and add to the count the end offset of each partition since the no. of messages in a topic is equal to the no. of messages in all the partitions of that topic.

Comment: Is it not necessary to add `config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");` ? If the consumer starts after the senders, it might not see all messages in the topic and the count would be wrong

Comment: @grog I omitted all the properties. But, I think we are not consuming, but only getting the end offsets. Is it really important?

Comment: I am unsure, that's why I asked, I do a similar test and if I do not put that property, the default value makes it so the consumer does not see any messages, and fails the test. I do however also check the content of the message, so maybe in this case it's not needed, just double checking

Comment: @grog It worked for me even if the config is not set to `earliest` but `poll` seems to be important though

Comment: Once some records have been deleted due to retention limits, the count you'll get will be incorrect. You need to take `beginningOffsets()` into account.

Comment: @MickaelMaison You mean to say, we should subtract beginningOffsets() from endOffsets() for each partition?

Comment: @JavaTechnical yes, that will tell you how many records are currently in the topic.